# Are there any introductory documents about Nvidia's NGX SDK?

Tags: nvidia, video-processing

Are there any introductory documents about Nvidia's NGX SDK?

My initial intention was to add a video-super-resolution feature to my project. Then I find that Nvidia's NGX seems to be a good solution. I downloaded the NGX SDK(https://developer.nvidia.cn/rtx/ngx/download) and opened the video-super-resolution cpp sample code. Then I was confused by those specific classes and types regarding encoding/decoding, RGB/YUV colorspaces, ffmpeg muxer/demuxer, nvenc/nvdec(seem to be nvidia encoder), etc.
So I want to know if there are introductory documnets about video processing (especially using nvidia's sdk) so that I can have some basic knowladge about those sample codes above. Thanks!